# Using commas in URL's can break the URL sometimes?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, hyperlink, seo

Is anyone aware of any problems with using commas in SEO friendly URL's? I'm working with some software that uses a lot of commas in it's SEO friendly URL's; but I am 100% certain I have seen some instances where some programs/platforms don't recognize the URL correctly & cut the "linking" of the URL off after the first comma.

I just tested this out with thunderbird, gmail, hotmail & on a SMF forum with no problems; however I know I have seen the issue before.

So my question is, is there anything in particular that would cause some platforms to stop linking URL's with a comma? Such as a certain character after the comma?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There will be *countless* implementations that will cut the automatical linking at that point. As with many other characters, too. But that’s not a problem because of using these characters, but because of a wrong/incomplete implementation.

See for example this very site, Stack Overflow. It will cut off the link at the `*` when manually entering/pasting this URL ([see bug](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2254/24166); in case it gets fixed, here’s a [screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52W7W.png)):

- http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.example.com/

But when using the hyperlink syntax, it works fine:

- http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.example.com/

The `*` character is allowed in an HTTP URL path, so the link detection *should* have recognized the first URL instead of breaking it at the occurence of `*`.

---

Regarding the comma:

The comma is a [reserved character](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) and its meaning is relevant for the URL [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) (bold emphasis mine):

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> considered opaque by the generic syntax.  URI producing applications
> often use the reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit
> scheme-specific or dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For
> example, the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are
> often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to
> that segment.  **The comma (",") reserved character is often used for
> similar purposes.**  For example, one URI producer might use a segment
> such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version 1.1 of
> "name", whereas another might use a segment such as "name,1.1" to
> indicate the same.

So, if you don’t intend to use the comma for the function it has as reserved character, you may want to percent-encode it with `%2C`. Users copying such an URL from their browser’s address bar would paste it in the encoded form, so it should work almost everywhere.

However, especially *because* it’s a reserved character, the unencoded form should work, too.