# comma in the URL , google ignore all after comma

Tags: string, url, routes

My site have links contains comma. eg. http://example.com/productName,product2123123.html
I set sitemap of this links and google webmaser tools report information that url is not found.
I see google ignore all after comma in url and try index http://example.com/productName that is error url and site generate 404.

Google have bug ? or i must change routing of my site ? or change comma to "%2C", but this could remove my actual offer from google ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this could help you but maybe this could help you understand more of what your problem is. Try reading the following links:

[Using commas in URL's can break the URL sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663813/using-commas-in-urls-can-break-the-url-sometimes)

[Are you using commas in your URLs? Here’s what you need to know.](https://www.searchenginenews.com/sample/content/are-you-using-commas-in-your-urls-heres-what-you-need-to-know)

[Google SEO News and Discussion Forum](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4242479.htm)

Comment: Now I find: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/webmasters/webmasters/dllXnQLVMps
It's know problem of google sitemap.
But google dont inform about this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35653?hl=en