# Possible side effect using comma in querystring?

Tags: url, query-string, urlencode, rfc3986

I'd like to use `,` in URL querystring value but [it is reserved character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375597/361100). However, we can see many e-commerce sites give comma-galore querystring urls in these days.

What do we consider when we use `,` in querystring? Should it be encoded as `%2c` always?

Note that my server-side frameworks are ASP.NET WebApi, dJango, and Node.js.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The URI standard doesn’t define any delimiters for the [query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4). So none of the reserved characters have a special role there, they all represent data.

The query component [may contain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816380/1591669) the following characters:

> - `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`
> - `0`-`9`
> - `/` `?` `:` `@` `!` `$` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `;` `=` `-` `.` `_` `~`
> - percent-encoded characters

**So you may use `,` and/or `%2C` in the query component.** Note that `,` and `%2C` are not equivalent for normalization purposes (because `,` is part of the *reserved* set).

All of the above is about the generic URI syntax. URI schemes may define additional delimiters (from the *reserved* set) for certain components, but the [`http`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1)/[`https`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.2) URI scheme spec doesn’t do this for the query component.

A possible side effect (like with many other allowed characters, too) is that [some auto-linking algorithms might not work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14677091/1591669).

(The applications you use may of course do something specific with `,` in query strings, but this would be nothing special about this character, it could happen with any other character, too.)